# Pull down to refresh using native scrolling in iOS5 website

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, css

Is there an implementation in javascript/css3 that works in the webkit browser?

Answer (score 0):

Sencha Touch has this feature and it works in Webkit. http://www.sencha.com/

But I guess it might be overkill to use that framework just for that single feature...